# How to force Visual Studio to use the .NET4.x debugger even when the startup program is .NET2

Tags: debugging, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012

OK, here's the scenario: I am developing a COM component in C# and C++. I have recently upgraded the development from .NET2 in VS2008 to .NET4 in VS2010. Testing involves running a separate application. The test program has a "Go" button which loads the COM component and calls its functions. However the test program runs under .NET2.

Now, since the upgrade to .NET4 I can no longer simply put the path of the test program into the "Start external program" field of the Debug properties page and press start. If I do this no symbols are loaded for my component, it doesn't appear in the modules list and can't be debugged. After a lot of puzzling I finally discovered that I now need to start the external program first. I then open the "Attach to Process" dialog. When I select the test program's process the "Attach to:" box shows "Automatic: Managed (V3.5,v3.0,v2.0) code". I have to press the Select button and specifically select "Managed v4.5, v4.0" before attaching. I then press the Go button on the test program and everything works.

So here's the question: How do I get Visual Studio to start the .NET4.x debugger by default when I press Start in VS, so that I don't have to go through this whole Attach To Process malarkey every time (and so that those who come after me don't have the same problem)?

Comment: You can force the test program to execute on CLR v4 by just rebuilding it with another framework target or with an app.exe.config file, `<supportedRuntime>` element.  You are not *really* testing COM interop in this scenario, the CLR will detect that it is talking to a .NET class.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I can't rebuild the test program but the app.exe.config trick works. I didn't know you could do that. However it's not as convenient as µS putting something in the debug properties in VS, which I would have thought was quite feasible.

Comment: Exact same issue here, thanks for saving the day.  This was pissing me off to no end, the debugger kept defaulting to "Automatic: Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0)" even though I was using .NET4.  How'd Microsoft screw this up so bad.